# PHP Decision Tree Implementation (ID3 or C4.5)

Tags: php, machine-learning, neural-network, decision-tree

I want to implement a decision tree (machine learning) algorithm in PHP. I've searched far and wide on Google and can find nothing in PHP.

Does anyone know a tutorial or function in PHP for implementing a descision tree?

Comment: http://kaising.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/task-1-investigate-decision-trees-and-quinlans-id3-ai-system/

Comment: This is not homework, I'm not in school, this is part of an important project. I don't know how to implement it, that's why I'm looking for a tutorial or implementation for PHP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467871/what-is-a-loosely-typed-language

Comment: Some one has written a k-cluster algorithm in php http://johntron.com/programming/k-cluster-algorithm-in-php/

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking specifically for Php code or any other languages are ok ?

You can start from the source code of original decision tree algorithm-C4.5.It is public but has some restrictions I think. http://www.rulequest.com/Personal/

Here is a good tutorial that you may want to refer : http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~dbd/cs831/notes/ml/dtrees/c4.5/tutorial.html

Weka implementations for decision tree J48 is available at : https://svn.scms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk/weka/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/trees/J48.java

If you are familiar with Python Orange C4.5 source code is available at : http://orange.biolab.si/

I do not work with PhP so I am not aware of any implementations in it. But all above implementations(C++,Java,or Python) are worthwhile too look.

Comment: Hmmm... I've seen all 3 of those before. I am specifically looking for a PHP implementation. Perhaps none exist...

Answer (score 0):

Albeit being commented and documented in Japanese, this seems to be pretty close to what you're looking for: https://github.com/kokukuma/php-decision-tree

Answer (score 0):

This is the most recent implementation of the C4.5 Algorithm in PHP on GitHub as of 2019: [PHP-C45](https://github.com/juliardi/C45).

I'm currently using it and it's very efficient too.